# Specify a Django model field as a query expression

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

#### How do I specify that a model field is implemented by a database expression instead of a table column?

I have this model:

```py
class URLProbe(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_URL_LENGTH)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status_code = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # The HTTP status code
    error = models.TextField(blank=True)  # stores non-HTTP errors, e.g. connection failures

    def ok(self):
        return self.status_code == 200
    ok.boolean = True
    ok.admin_order_field = Case(
        When(status_code__exact=200, then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )

    def errmsg(self):
        if self.ok():
            return ''
        if self.status_code is not None:
            return f'Error: HTTP status {self.status_code}'
        return self.error
    errmsg.admin_order_field = Case(
        When(status_code__exact=200, then=Value('')),
        When(status_code__isnull=False,
             then=Concat(Value('Error: HTTP status '), 'status_code')),
        default='error',
        output_field=CharField()
    )
```

The model represents an attempt to retrieve an url, recording whether the HTTP call succeeded or what the error was.

The `ok` and `errmsg` fields here are implemented as methods, but I want to be able to use them in the Django admin as regular fields (sort/filter on them) and to sort and/or filter on them in queries. That is possible, but I need to define the query expression multiple times: in an `admin_order_field`, in a Django admin custom filter, and in queries where I want to use them. So that duplicates a lot of code, both for the multiple expressions and between the query expression and the python method.

#### What I would like to do

is define fields as query expressions, allowing any database operations to occur without further configuration. Something like:

```
class URLProbe(models.Model):
    ...

    ok = ExpressionField(Case(
        When(status_code__exact=200, then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ))

    errmsg = ExpressionField(Case(
        When(ok__exact=True, then=Value('')),
        When(status_code__isnull=False,
             then=Concat(Value('Error: HTTP status '), 'status_code')),
        default='error',
        output_field=CharField()
    ))
```

However I have not been able to find anything like `ExpressionField` or a way to do something similar. Does this exist? Can this be implemented in Django?

**update:** I found something that works partially. I can specify a custom manager with a default queryset that includes `ok` and `errmsg` as annotations. That allows me to use them in custom queries without duplicating the expression, but unfortunately the admin does not accept them as fields and throws SystemCheckErrors. I feel that it should work if it were not for that system check.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using the base Django ORM you cannot sort by properties since those operations are done at SQL level and that field is not stored in the database.

There is a project to denormalize models, that basically calculates and stores this calculated values behind the curtain for you, that would probably serve your purpose:
https://github.com/django-denorm/django-denorm

So you would use it like:

```
    @denormalized(models.CharField, max_length=100)
    def errmsg(self):
       if self.ok():
            return ''
       if self.status_code is not None:
            return f'Error: HTTP status {self.status_code}'
```

Comment: You can sort on these kind of computed properties if you `.annotate()` a queryset with the expression to calculate the property in the database. 
This `denormalized` is one way to solve it, but it duplicates data which I prefer to avoid in this case.

Comment: yes, I didn't specify it in my answer, but I agree with you that is not an optimal solution, I also prefer to use your approach. I just answered to the OP about a way to be able to define it at model level, since he wanted to define it just once